# Problema al usar 09 en C

Tags: c

tal vez es una boludes lo que pregunto, pero no se por que no me deja usar 09 en una condición, me tira erro, pongo otro numero y no pasa nada, pero con el 09 no puedo. Ojala me puedan dar una mano, saludos!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){    
  int d,m,a;

  printf (" Indique una fecha: ");
  scanf ("%d %d %d",&d,&m,&a);

  if (d > 31 || m > 12  ){
    printf (" No es una fecha valida!");
  } else {
    if ( m == 01 || m == 03 || m == 05 || m == 07 ||  m == 10 || m == 12 && d <= 31  ) {
      printf ("\n\n Es una fecha valida!");
    }

    if ( m == 04 || m == 06  ) {
      printf ("\n\n Es una fecha valida!!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el link broh,entonces debería cambiar el  tipo de dato de la variable? osea que no sea INT.?

Comment: Lo único que tienes que hacer es quitar el `0` del principio del número: `09` -> **no**; `9`  -> **si**.

Comment: si si de eso me di cuenta,pero pense q habia alguna forma de poder usar el 08 y el 09, como es para indicar una fecha,queda mejor asi,pero bueno,lo cambiare.Muchas gracias y disculpa las molestias,un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

El problema que yo veo, es que al usar un número que inicia con 0, el compilador lo considera como un número en octal, y por lo tanto el dígito 9 como el dígito 8, no son válidos en un número octal.

Si quieres usar el nueve, tenes que hacerlo sin el cero.

En tu ejemplo estas usando los números 01, 02, ..., 07, hasta ahí no hay problema porque a pesar de que los has escritos octal coinciden con los estan en decimal. El problema viene cuando queres representar un numero mayor a 7 que es el 8, en octal es el 10, que para que el compilador lo diferencie del decimal al octal tienes que anteceder el 0, entonces se escribe asi: "010"

Por eso te recomiendo que aprendas a diferenciar en escribir un en octal y en decimal.

Comment: Si la verdad no tenia idea que existía el octal,ahora ya lo comprendí,muchas gracias por tomarte un tiempo en responder. Un saludo!